# how to change opaque property based on some condition in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to show notification in my report like if the data table in my report holds the rows with yellow color then  textfield the opaque property set to be true otherwise it should be false. somewhat like this...

```
txtfiled1 Shows UnPlanned Leaves
```

In above statement as I told u earlier that if my data table holds rows having yellow backcolor then the "txtfield1" 's opaque property must be set to true otherwise it must be false. How can I achieve this ? any help wolid be appreciable...

Comment: AFAIK for use background color != white, then opaque must be always true. Question is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it is causing me trouble with equals method in a condition, But using integer comparision with == operator give me what i wanted.

```
new Boolean($F{unplanned}.toString().equals("1")) fails me 
new Boolean($F{unplanned}.intValue() == 1) give success
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick guess:

```
$F{unplanned}.toString().trim().equals("1") == true
```

But as you're using toString() there, I suppose the source format of $F{unplanned} is integer anyways.